# Multilingual meetingmins?

Tags: translator

I want to type a meeting report and encountered the class [meetingmins](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/meetingmins) which adresses my needs. Is it possible to change the language (in my case french)?
I'm considering going through the `meetingmins.dtx` and changing all "by hand".

Is there any clever way to do this?

I guess my question is heading towards translating `meetingmins`. I would appreciate any help towards this goal ([Brian Beitzel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/19862/nicola-talbot)?)

Here is a MWE.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{meetingmins}

\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\setcommittee{Des mots en français}
\setmembers{
\chair{A.~French},
2.~French
}
\setdate{Mars 11, 2015}
\setpresent{
\chair{A.~French},
2.~French
}
\absent{Bad.~French \textit{(sabbatical)}}
\alsopresent{Good.~French}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Announcements}
\begin{hiddenitems}
\item
Le sous-titre n'est pas en français.
\item
Tout est en anglais!
\end{hiddenitems}
\section{Comment modifier?}
\subsection{Les commandes prédéfinies?}
\subsubsection{La classe .dtx?}
Mais alors le package "meetingmins" doit être changé...? 
\end{document}
```

Comment: There is no example to test, but can't you just change the language as a global option? Maybe with the support of package `babel`? Please add a [minimall working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/html/).

Comment: i tried "\usepackage[francais]{babel}", but the nothing changes (i.e. the class does not seem to be set-up to react to language changes).

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/html/).

Comment: `meetingmins` is in no way related to `minutes`. Everything in `meetingmins` is hardcoded, best way to get language support would be to do a feature request with the maintainer. Sorry.

Comment: I contacted the author, but he's too buzy. Guess I'm going to create my own "template", as things get a bit too deep for my skills.. (i.e. going through the .dtx and "recompiling" the class)

Comment: @Johannes_B, can you post your comment "Everything in meetingmins is hardcoded, best way to get language support would be to do a feature request with the maintainer." as an answer so I can close the question?

Comment: I wouldn't really consider that an answer. If you do change the hardcoded stuff, please be sure to give different names to the modified files. I'll see what i can do to write up a better answer.